# Discord.js canvas TypeError: sources.map is not a function using merge-images

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord.js

I'm trying to make an image using canvas and merge-images but i get error "TypeError: sources.map is not a function"

```js
const mergeImages = require('merge-images')
const { Canvas, Image } = require('canvas');
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'avatar',
    description: 'avatar',
    async execute(message, args) {               
        let b64 = await mergeImages('assets/colors/yellow.png', { Canvas: Canvas, Image: Image });
        b64 = b64.split(';base64,').pop();
        await message.channel.send({ files: [{ attachment: Buffer.from(b64, 'base64'), name: `avatar.png` }] });
    }
}
```

EDIT: the "yellow.png" file is located here

[image: yellow.png]

Comment: What's your file structure? where is this file located and where the "yellow.png"?? update your question with that info

Comment: edited and by file structure do you mean the file type?

Comment: instead of "items = ['../../assets/colors/yellow.png']" use this: Define "const path  = require('path');" and "let items = [path.join(__dirname, './../../assets/colors/yellow.png')]"

Comment: weird still gives the same error

Comment: the yellow.png file is just a transparent image of an among us crewmate dunno what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

[merge-images#mergeImages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-images#nodejs-usage) expects an Array, instead, you provided a String: `let b64 = await mergeImages('assets/colors/yellow.png', { Canvas: Canvas, Image: Image });`

**'assets/colors/yellow.png'** is a single String, not an Array. The package is trying to call [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on this String you provided, change it to **`['assets/colors/yellow.png']`** instead, or preferably, an array with **multiple** paths to images for the package to merge together.